# how can I find the imaginary matrix inverse without using the calculator?

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, matrix-equations

I have non-graphical calculator and I am strgguling to find way around to solve the imaginary matrix inverse becuase the calculator  does not accept imaginary matrix.

I fould a way for solving if the matrix has just imaginary part such as 
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1j & 3j  \\
    2j & 4j  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

The inverse for this matrix can be found by
find the inverse for 
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 3  \\
    2 & 4  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

then multiply the matrix by $$ -j$$

The inverse equal

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & \frac32  \\
    1 & - \frac12  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
*-j
$$

The final form is

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2j & -j\frac32  \\
    -1j &  j\frac12  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I am looking for a way to solve the following matrix by similar way:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    3+1j & 2+3j  \\
    3+2j & 2+4j  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    3+1j & 2+3j & 2+5j  \\
    3+2j & 2+4j & 4+5j  \\
    5+1j & 4+4j & 1+2j  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Why is this different to inversion of a real matrix? The same process leads to the inverse matrix$$\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}^{-1}=\frac1{ad-bc}\pmatrix{d&-b\\-c&a}$$

Comment: It is not different. What I need is a way around to use calculator to find the inverse for a matrix without any imaginary number inside the matrix. Because I face different size of matrices such as 3 by 3. By this way which is mentioned above it will be much easier using the calculator without involving in much math. @PeterForeman

Comment: Then use the same method you would for inverting an $n\times n$ real matrix. I suggest [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Finding_the_inverse_of_a_matrix).

Comment: @PeterForeman I know gaussain eleimination but what I need I just need to find way that I can use the real part + the imaginary part with out $$ j $$ inside the matrix. why I need it ? because I can do the real inverse by the calculator and then just insert the $$ j $$  in the last step

Comment: I'm confused. You now say you are using a calculator but your question explicitly states "without a calculator". Either way I believe my answer is what you are after.

Comment: I meant use the calculator just to solve it as real matrix. because non-graphical calculator cannot insert $$ j $$ in the matrix

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of a $2\times 2$ matrix is given by 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\frac1{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix},
$$
so you can calculate that explicitly. For a bigger matrix you could use row reduction, where again all you need to do are simple sums and multiplications.

Answer (score 0):

$$(A+iB)^{-1}=(A+BA^{-1}B)^{-1}+i(B+AB^{-1}A)^{-1}$$
where $A$, $B$ are invertible real $n\times n$ matrices. [Reference](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/49373-complex-matrix-inversion-by-real-matrix-inversion)